# Android emulator throws system UI not responding

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Although this question has been answered quite some times before but the solution is not working for me.

My android emulator throws `system UI not responding` over and over. I've tried the below solution:

```
1.Open AVD Manager. enter image description here 
2.Click to edit button for your device. enter image description here 
3.Select Hardware in the Graphics drop down menu.
```

Using:

- android studio version: 4.1.3
- flutter: Flutter 2.0.6

Can anyone provide any solution?

Comment: Try wiping the emulator's data & then cold boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there you do not need to all that stuff just go to your AVD manager and click that down arrow i.e DropDown arrow and click on cold boot but make sure you are not running the device at that time as it may cause some error. It is not a permanent solution to the problem it works fine for 4-5 hours as I m not able to find the perfect solution. So it works for me and I hope it works for you too. Whoever seeing this after 2025 Please Reply me to see if I m alive. Bye!